# meteorjs -- Problems with the accounts-twitch package & OAuth2

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, meteor, twitch

Today, I started a new project (IRC Bot, etc.) to be used with Twitch.TV's chat servers.

I wanted to use the accounts-twitch package that I found on Atmosphere, and had to manually install it (editing the package.js file) due to a deprecated dependency on accounts-oauth2-helper.

After getting it to properly install, my app crashes on startup now.  It tosses the following error before dying, and I don't know how to fix it:

```
[[[[[ ~/projects/wasdbot ]]]]]

=> Started MongoDB.
=> Starting your app...

W20140605-15:22:42.283(-4)? (STDERR) 
W20140605-15:22:42.350(-4)? (STDERR) /home/misutowolf/.meteor/tools/5bf1690853/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20140605-15:22:42.350(-4)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20140605-15:22:42.350(-4)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20140605-15:22:42.351(-4)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot call method 'registerService' of undefined
W20140605-15:22:42.351(-4)? (STDERR)     at Package (packages/accounts-twitch/twitch_server.js:2)
W20140605-15:22:42.351(-4)? (STDERR)     at Package (packages/accounts-twitch/twitch_server.js:82)
W20140605-15:22:42.351(-4)? (STDERR)     at packages/accounts-twitch.js:123:4
W20140605-15:22:42.351(-4)? (STDERR)     at packages/accounts-twitch.js:130:3
W20140605-15:22:42.352(-4)? (STDERR)     at /home/misutowolf/projects/wasdbot/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:155:10
W20140605-15:22:42.352(-4)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20140605-15:22:42.352(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/misutowolf/.meteor/tools/5bf1690853/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20140605-15:22:42.352(-4)? (STDERR)     at /home/misutowolf/projects/wasdbot/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8
W20140605-15:22:43.456(-4)? (STDERR) 
W20140605-15:22:43.457(-4)? (STDERR) /home/misutowolf/.meteor/tools/5bf1690853/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20140605-15:22:43.457(-4)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20140605-15:22:43.458(-4)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20140605-15:22:43.463(-4)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot call method 'registerService' of undefined
W20140605-15:22:43.463(-4)? (STDERR)     at Package (packages/accounts-twitch/twitch_server.js:2)
W20140605-15:22:43.464(-4)? (STDERR)     at Package (packages/accounts-twitch/twitch_server.js:82)
W20140605-15:22:43.464(-4)? (STDERR)     at packages/accounts-twitch.js:123:4
W20140605-15:22:43.464(-4)? (STDERR)     at packages/accounts-twitch.js:130:3
W20140605-15:22:43.465(-4)? (STDERR)     at /home/misutowolf/projects/wasdbot/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:155:10
W20140605-15:22:43.465(-4)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20140605-15:22:43.465(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/misutowolf/.meteor/tools/5bf1690853/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20140605-15:22:43.466(-4)? (STDERR)     at /home/misutowolf/projects/wasdbot/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8
W20140605-15:22:44.622(-4)? (STDERR) 
W20140605-15:22:44.624(-4)? (STDERR) /home/misutowolf/.meteor/tools/5bf1690853/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20140605-15:22:44.625(-4)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20140605-15:22:44.625(-4)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20140605-15:22:44.628(-4)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot call method 'registerService' of undefined
W20140605-15:22:44.629(-4)? (STDERR)     at Package (packages/accounts-twitch/twitch_server.js:2)
W20140605-15:22:44.629(-4)? (STDERR)     at Package (packages/accounts-twitch/twitch_server.js:82)
W20140605-15:22:44.630(-4)? (STDERR)     at packages/accounts-twitch.js:123:4
W20140605-15:22:44.630(-4)? (STDERR)     at packages/accounts-twitch.js:130:3
W20140605-15:22:44.630(-4)? (STDERR)     at /home/misutowolf/projects/wasdbot/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:155:10
W20140605-15:22:44.631(-4)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20140605-15:22:44.631(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/misutowolf/.meteor/tools/5bf1690853/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20140605-15:22:44.631(-4)? (STDERR)     at /home/misutowolf/projects/wasdbot/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Seems like the problem is this call to Accounts.oauth.registerService, in twitch_server.js, but I don't really know how to go about fixing it.

I also can't seem to find anything about this oauth stuff in their API docs, anywhere, or maybe I'm looking in the wrong place, or maybe I'm missing a package that I should have included?

All I added to my project is accounts-twitch, accounts-ui, and coffeescript, as of right now.  I haven't written any code yet, just trying to fire up Meteor.

Any help would be amazing.  I really appreciate everyone's time beforehand.